# Explanation for photovoltaic circuit

Tags: electrical-engineering, circuits, solar-energy, circuit-design, photovoltaics

My background is in Environmental Science, although I have recently been taught in the basics for energy engineering especially for solar panels.

I'm currently using PVsyst to build solar panels on a given building at a given location. However, I'm finding it difficult to explain and understand this diagram with my limited circuit knowledge.

Can someone offer a detailed explanation of the components along with what they represent in the network and what the entire picture means?  I know that 1. represents a diode, and it looks to me that 2. represents a European-resistor, I partially know this because of basic practice in LtSpice.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Diode** Like you assumed
2. **Panels**: These are the PV panenls that produce current. They produce DC current I and DC voltage V
3. **Inverter**: the inverter converts the DC current and Voltage from the panels to AC voltage and current, which is in sync with the Grid. This part is responsible for converting the energy from the panels into the energy that the grid can transfer.
4. **User**: the user is a load that is not in the grid. This makes sense in the case of net metering, where the producer of energy can use some of the energy for their own needs.
5. **Grid**: this is the electrical distribution grid. This transfers the energy to other parts where it maybe consumed.

Comment: What do these compoenents, fitted as they are, represent as a synthesis for the image above? Is it how energy passes through the circuit, for a particular function, and that function is the transfer of energy through the distribution grid? Which component plays the biggest role in this case?

Comment: I'm not certain I understand your question. I will hazard a guess and say that they represent a fully functional unit of PV power (a string of PV panels with everything required to connect to the grid).  All of them play a significant role. The least important is probably 4 or 5 (one of them).